# What is the point of such handle redirection as 1<&2?

Tags: redirection, stdout, stderr, handle

According to what is said [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN):

> For example, the following command redirects handle 2 (that is,
> STDERR) into handle 1 (that is, STDOUT):
>
> 1<&2

I understand why we might need to apply the redirection such as `2>&1`, but I can't see any reason for applying `1<&2`. Could anybody clarify this for me? Thank you in advance.